# fluent UI fluent-text-field skips some text when user writes

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side, fluent-ui

Im using Fluent UI web component in my Blazor Server Side project, and when the user types a text into a `fluent-text-field`, some of the written text is skipped, is there a fix for it or I should just change all my `fluent-text-fields`?
an example can be found here: [Example](https://blazorfluentui.azurewebsites.net/textFieldPage)

writing in the field labeled as 'standard' or 'Postal Code autocomplete' will create the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've taken a look to the source code of Fluent UI. As I expected, it seems they are using the event `@oninput` for non multiline text fields: [Source](https://github.com/BlazorFluentUI/BlazorFluentUI/blob/main/src/BlazorFluentUI.CoreComponents/TextField/TextFieldBase.razor):

```
value=@(BindConverter.FormatValue(CurrentValueAsString))
@oninput=@(EventCallback.Factory.CreateBinder<string?>(this, __value => CurrentValueAsString = __value, CurrentValueAsString))
```

Because of this, on every character you type, you get some network time before it gets processed and updated on the client side which explains the lags.

This issue should globally not be happening locally or on Blazor WASM because there isn't any network time.

For Multiline text fields, they are using `@bind` which doesn't produce the issue:

```
@bind-value=@CurrentValue
@bind-value:event="oninput"
```

This [link](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/14242) addresses more precisely why `@input` can be problematic on Blazor Server Side and the differences with `@bind`.

About how you can still use this, unfortunately, I didn't see any parameter that fix this apart from using Multiline text fields. However, it seems the developers of the library will hardly be updating it or improving it. I suggest you consider another library for new developements ([Github repository](https://github.com/BlazorFluentUI/BlazorFluentUI)):

> We will not be adding any new functionality and bug fixing will be minimal.

Comment: It's unfortunate that it still hasn't been fixed after being release for quite some time, I guess I have to manually change every fluent input to a normal or a custom input, thanks for your help @T.Trassoudaine

Comment: @AIDENIV I think, from the tags of the repository, that it was more intended for Blazor WASM than server side.

Answer (score 1):

maintainer of BlazorFluentUI here.

We've moved our attention to the Microsoft.Fast.Components.FluentUI library. See https://github.com/microsoft/fast-blazor for the source and https://aka.ms/fluentui-blazor for a demosite

Comment: thank you for the information, I will consider using the new library in the future.